# JavaScript: Prevent a link navigation with unknown position.

Tags: javascript

I have made a plugin which uses click events, however sometimes my clickable element may be within an A link, however it might not be a direct child, is there a good way to stop the a link from firing whilst not knowing it's position?

For example:

```
<div id="lightbox">
          <a href="">
            <div class="twocol">
              <img src="http://www.ducati.com/cms-web/fs//MediaGalleries/345/MediaGallery_345008/SBK-1199Panigale-S_2012_Studio_Tricolore_B01_1920x1280.jpg/SBK-1199Panigale-S_2012_Studio_Tricolore_B01_1920x1280.mediagallery_output_image_[1920x1080].jpg" alt="Ducati Panigale 1199 - Image 1" class="responsive-img">
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <div class="twocol">
              <img src="https://www.asphaltandrubber.com/wp-content/gallery/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-with-jensen-beeler/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-cota-jensen-beeler-07.jpg" alt="Ducati Panigale 1199 - Image 2" class="responsive-img">
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: What has the position got to do with anything?

Comment: As usually you can just get the parent node, but if it isn't a direct parent...

Comment: It shouldn't matter, you can select ancestors...

Comment: Couldnt you simply e.preventDefault() on all events??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if your clickable element is always in a element with a class name.

But one way to do it is to check if the parent is a `<a>` tag and add `event.preventDefault`.

Comment: I know this, but the <a> may not be a direct parent